What is the difference between `@PersistenceContext`and constructor injection?
When you use constructor (or field) injection do you loose any benefits of @PersistenceContext? I understand that you can configure EntityManager with the annotation but if you do not need to configure anything, what is the best practice?
Also, does it bring value with  @Transactional  in Spring Boot application?
With constructor injection:
@Transactional
@Repository
public class UserRepository {

  private final EntityManager entityManager;

  public UserRepository(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
  }

  public void createUser(UserDetails user) {
    entityManager.persist(user);
  }

With @PersistenceContext injection:
@Transactional
@Repository
public class UserRepository {

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  public void createUser(UserDetails user) {
    entityManager.persist(user);
  }

